# errors developing first android app

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio-2.2

I'm developing first android app, and it consist of a percentage calculator. has two text boxes for number input, one text view, to display result, and one button. When I run the app, it is giving me these errors about classes. I went over android.develpers site to look for the button documentation, and seems to be correct. However, I don't know what the problem is. This is the code I implemented.

```
//calculator variables
TextView totalTxtView;
EditText numberTxt;
EditText percentTxt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //calculator code starts here ------------------//

    //references
    percentTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentTxt);
    numberTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTxt);
    totalTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTxtView);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something in response to button click
            float percent = float.parseFloat(percentTxt.getText().toString());
            float number = float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
            float result = numbrer * ( percent * 0.10);
            totalTxtView.setText(Float.toString(result));
        }
    });
```

this is the error log

```
Error:(41, 39) error: class expected
Error:(41, 49) error: ';' expected
Error:(41, 81) error: ';' expected
Error:(42, 38) error: class expected
Error:(42, 48) error: ';' expected
Error:(42, 79) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 8.936 secs
Information:7 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
    enter code here
```

any help appreciated

Comment: `float result = numbrer * ( percent * 0.10);` --- you have a typo in this line by the looks of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you look too deeply into the debugging, I believe you've made a typo.

If I understand your logic correctly, `result` is supposed to be the number `number` as a percentage given by `percentage`. Then you should actually replace:

```
float result = numbrer * ( percent * 0.10);
```

With

```
float result = number * ( percent * 0.01);
```

If not, then to correct your typo to:

```
float result = number * ( percent * 0.10);
```

Then update your program and see what happens.

Comment: thanks, it seems like a dumb question, but I tried stepping through the debugger, and it pointed me to class errors. It completely threw me off. The debugger couldn't pin point the error more exactly.

Comment: after correcting the error (typo) still don't work. I'm getting 7 errors when running app. and they all. Do I need to import any class.